# Illustrate the declare and reassign of int with python int class

Tags: python, integer, immutability

Since every object in python has the following properties

1. Type
2. Value
3. Identity -object’s address in memory

```
x =300
```

When I am executing the above code in python an int class instance is created with value 300. X points to the identity of the object

```
x = x + 233
```

In this time a new int class instance is created with value = 533 and now x points the identity of this object.

Can anyone explain this workflow with python int class?

Comment: Have you looked at [Integer Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html)? From docs:

`The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object. So it should be possible to change the value of 1. I suspect the behaviour of Python in this case is undefined. :-)
`

Answer (score 1):

```
When we execute the code x=5, We create a new int object in python.
```

Actually not:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> y = 10
>>> x is y

True
>>> x = 1000
>>> y = 1000
>>> x is y
```

Python has a small cache for small ints. So when you create two variables with values less than `256` you actually reference to the same object in the memory.

```
When we execute x = x + 6, x object changes.
```

Actually, not :) `int`-s are immutable in Python, so you don't change existing object. You create a new object:

```
>>> id(x)
140352270947408
>>> x = x + 1
>>> id(x)
140352270947384
```

Comment: well. Thanks demas. I am wondering that `int ` class of python doesn't do anything with above codes

Comment: Demas, I have updated the question. This answer helps me a lot. I need to know how python create the int object, how it changes from one object to another object (in my case,the reference x)